# Haskell: Name multiple arguments in a nice way

Tags: haskell

I am working on a virtual stack machine for my school project. Everything works fine, but this is what I have as the control function of the program run:

```
run :: Program -> SubprogramDir -> Memory -> ComputerStack -> Input -> Output -> Output
run EOP _ _ _ _ out = out
run (lbl `Marks` prg) dir mem stack inp out = run prg dir mem stack inp out
run (ins `Then` prg) dir mem stack inp out =
  case ins of
    (TA addr) -> (run prg dir mem (Stack.push (Left addr) stack) inp out) 
    (TV val) -> (run prg dir mem (Stack.push (Right val) stack) inp out)
    DR -> (dr prg dir mem stack inp out)
    ST -> (st prg dir mem stack inp out)
    WR -> (wr prg dir mem stack inp out)
    RD -> (rd prg dir mem stack inp out)
    AD -> (mathAction (+) prg dir mem stack inp out)
    SB -> (mathAction (-) prg dir mem stack inp out)
    MT -> (mathAction (*) prg dir mem stack inp out)
    DI -> (mathAction (div) prg dir mem stack inp out)
    (JU lbl) -> (ju lbl prg dir mem stack inp out)
    (JZ lbl) -> (jz lbl prg dir mem stack inp out)
```

This `dir mem stack inp out` keeps repeating everywhere and it looks terrible. Is there a way to lump it into one, let's say, tuple, and pass it to other functions? Or any other nicer way to write it?

Comment: At the very least, bundle the other parameters up into something like `data ExecutionEnvironment = EE SubprogramDIr Memory ComputerStack Input Output`, so you can define `run :: Program -> ExecutionEnvironment -> Output`. Record syntax will make it easier to deal with the `ExecutionEnvironment` argument when it isn't simply passed through as-is.

Comment: We might need some more context, though, to best refactor, and this might be more suited for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @MichielBorkent, that's great advice, but the link is not really appropriate to the context. Generally speaking, the GHC Trac wiki is for people delving into the development or internals of the GHC compiler, not people trying to learn Haskell!

Comment: @dfeuer Ah, good point... I cannot edit the link anymore. I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define an helper `call` function

```
run (ins `Then` prg) dir mem stack inp out =
  let call k = k prg dir mem stack inp out
  in case ins of
    TA addr -> (run prg dir mem (Stack.push (Left addr) stack) inp out) 
    TV val -> (run prg dir mem (Stack.push (Right val) stack) inp out)
    DR -> call dr
    ST -> call st
    WR -> call wr
    RD -> call rd
    AD -> call $ mathAction (+)
    SB -> call $ mathAction (-)
    MT -> call $ mathAction (*)
    DI -> call $ mathAction (div)
    JU lbl -> call $ ju lbl
    JZ lbl -> call $ jz lbl
```

Encapsulating all the common state variables in a data type seems more appropriate, though. Often, this execution state is called a "configuration" for your abstract machine. For instance,

```
data Config = Config SubprogramDir Memory ComputerStack Input Output
```

One can also turn this into a record.